How do I make valibot properly check constructor/function arguments?
Consider the following, note that a negative argument is checked:
use strictures;
use Moops;
use Data::Dx;

library MyTypes declares NonNegativeInt {
    # let's pretend
    # <http://p3rl.org/Types::Common::Numeric#PositiveOrZeroInt>
    # does not exist
    declare NonNegativeInt, as Int, where { $_ >= 0 };
};

class Span types MyTypes :ro {
    has from => isa => NonNegativeInt, required => true;
    has to => isa => NonNegativeInt, required => true;
    fun BUILD(InstanceOf["Span"] $self, HashRef $args) {
        die qq("from" $args->{from} must be smaller than "to" $args->{to})
            if $args->{from} > $args->{to};
    }
}

Dx Span->new(from => -123, to => 234); # throws as expected
Dx Span->new(from =>  123, to => 234); # lives as expected
Dx Span->new(from => 1123, to => 234); # throws as expected

__END__
cpanm -nv -L local strictures Moops Data::Dx
perl -I local/lib/perl5 index.pl

In the next piece of code, the refined type check declared in line 3 does not seem to happen.
import * as v from "valibot";

const NonNegativeBigInt = v.pipe(v.bigint(), v.toMinValue(0n));
type NonNegativeBigInt = v.InferOutput<typeof NonNegativeBigInt>;

class Span {
    readonly #from: NonNegativeBigInt;
    readonly #to: NonNegativeBigInt;
    constructor(readonly from: NonNegativeBigInt, readonly to: NonNegativeBigInt) {
        if (from > to) {
            throw new RangeError(`"from" ${from} must be smaller than "to" ${to}`);
        }
        this.#from = from;
        this.#to = to;
    }
    toString(): String {
        return `Span(${this.#from}, ${this.#to})`;
    }
}

console.log(new Span(-123n, 234n)); // lives, ???
console.log(new Span( 123n, 234n)); // lives as expected
console.log(new Span(1123n, 234n)); // throws as expected

/*
npm i -D tsx
npm i -S valibot
npx tsx index.ts
*/

What is going wrong here?

In TypeScript, types are erased during compilation. 1, 2
The code you showed defines both a value NonNegativeBigInt and also a type alias NonNegativeBigInt.
The value NonNegativeBigInt is never used in the program — except to infer the type alias (which is erased during compilation). The type NonNegativeBigInt is inferred as the type bigint — which refers to any BigInt primitive value (whether positive or negative).

Note: The TypeScript compiler isn’t currently capable of discriminating unbounded, non-literal, number-like types.

TS Playground
import * as v from "valibot";

const NonNegativeBigInt = v.pipe(v.bigint(), v.toMinValue(0n));
type NonNegativeBigInt = v.InferOutput<typeof NonNegativeBigInt>;
//   ^? type NonNegativeBigInt = bigint

This is identical to the following code, where the valibot package is not used at all:
TS Playground
class Span {
    readonly #from: bigint;
    readonly #to: bigint;
    constructor(readonly from: bigint, readonly to: bigint) {
        if (from > to) {
            throw new RangeError(`"from" ${from} must be smaller than "to" ${to}`);
        }
        this.#from = from;
        this.#to = to;
    }
    toString(): String {
        return `Span(${this.#from}, ${this.#to})`;
    }
}

When evaluating new Span(-123n, 234n), there is no runtime validation to enforce non-negative parameter values, so the conditional from > to evaluates to false and the RangeError is not thrown… resulting in a successful completion.
You can add runtime validation to enforce that the parameters are non-negative — for example:
TS Playground
constructor(from: bigint, to: bigint) {
    if (from < 0n) throw new RangeError(`"from" ${from} must be non-negative`);
    if (to < 0n) throw new RangeError(`"to" ${to} must be non-negative`);
    if (from > to) {
        throw new RangeError(`"from" ${from} must be smaller than "to" ${to}`);
    }
    this.#from = from;
    this.#to = to;
}

…then the negative argument will cause an exception as expected:
console.log(new Span(-123n, 234n)); // RangeError: "from" -123 must be non-negative


Here's an example of using the valibot parser API for similar runtime validation:

You can test this code in the Valibot Playground

TS Playground
import * as v from "valibot";

const nonNegativeBigIntSchema = v.pipe(
    v.bigint(),
    v.minValue(0n, "Arguments must be non-negative"),
);

const nonNegativeBigIntParser = v.parser(nonNegativeBigIntSchema);

class Span {
    readonly #from: bigint;
    readonly #to: bigint;
    constructor(from: bigint, to: bigint) {
        from = nonNegativeBigIntParser(from);
        to = nonNegativeBigIntParser(to);
        if (from > to) {
            throw new RangeError(`"from" ${from} must be smaller than "to" ${to}`);
        }
        this.#from = from;
        this.#to = to;
    }
    toString(): String {
        return `Span(${this.#from}, ${this.#to})`;
    }
}

console.log(new Span(-123n, 234n)); // ValiError: Arguments must be non-negative
console.log(new Span(123n, 234n)); // ok
console.log(new Span(1123n, 234n)); // RangeError: "from" 1123 must be smaller than "to" 234


tl;dr for people like me who got lost – the relevant changes are: toMinValue must be minValue; for each argument item manually add a run-time check, e.g. from = v.parser(NonNegativeBigInt)(from);
